# Manipular Data com comando Date

Tags: shell-script

Caros;

Tenho um problema muito simples, porem não estou conseguindo encontrar uma logica para isso. Tenho um arquivo com datas pré fixadas, exemplo 2017-10-31, gostaria de cada mudança de mês, esta data fosse acrescentada com o mês atual. Na data cima está mês 10 (Outubro), em novembro fosse alterado para 11 e assim por diante. Esta alteração poderia ser com um for + 1, porem quando chegar no 12, voltaria para 01, entretanto , o ano continuaria 2017 e não 2018. Acredito que o comando date teria algum argumento para isso e não utilizar algum script.

Tentei usar:

```
date +2016-10-26 +%m

date "+2016-10-26" --date="1 month"
```

Resolvido com o código (Gambiarra) abaixo

```
ano="$(date +%Y)"

dia=`cat mensal.txt | cut -d: -f3| sed s'/-/ -/g'| awk '{print $3}'| sed 's/-//g'`

DATA_ALVO="$(date +%m)"

echo $ano-$DATA_ALVO-$dia
```

Comment: faz um  if exemplo
if(mes == 12 window.mes != 'novoAno'){
 window.mes == 'novoAno'
}else{
ano + 1;
window.mes ==""
}

deu para entender a logica ? cria uma variavel global window.mes e depois quando o mes for doze e for acrescentando um novo mes ele vai ir para o else ai vc soma o  ano+1

Comment: Obrigado Marcos, resolvi conforme edição na minha pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que vc queira imprimir formatar a data antes de imprimir, o comando correto é:

```
date +%Y-%M-%d
```

terá a seguinte saída

```
2017-04-01
```

Quer declarar uma variável com a data atual...

```
var=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Imprimindo a variável

```
echo $var
2017-04-01
```

Voc^pode formatar a data de muitas formas, exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
var_ano=$(date +%Y)
var_mes=$(date +%m)
var_dia=$(date +%d)

echo "Estamos no ano de $var_ano dia $var_dia mes $var_mes"
```

saída

```
Estamos no ano de 2017 dia 01 mes 11
```

Leia mais sobre o comando date em --> https://linux.die.net/man/1/date

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria colocar algumas linhas do arquivo para melhor referência, mas com base na sua linha de comando acredito que isso resolva.

```
sed -i -r "s/:([^-]+-)[^-]+/:\1$(date +%m)/" arquivo
```